# Display data in Rich Textarea on (ajax success) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, richtextarea

Here My Code:

```
<textarea 
 class="textarea" id="about_us" placeholder="Place some text here"
 style="width: 100%; height: 100%; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"
>
</textarea >
```

And My JavaSript code is **I Recieve Data But Only Rich Textarea us not showing**
[See This RichTextarea Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfLX9.png)

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('click', '.editbtn', function(){  
          var Pedit_id = $(this).attr("id");  
          $.ajax({  
               url:"../fetch/editproduct.php",  
               method:"POST",  
               data:{Pedit_id:Pedit_id},  
               dataType:"json",  
               success:function(data){ 
                    $('#about_us').val(data.product_dec);

               }  
          });  
     });
});
</script>
```

Please tell me where I mistake because I want to get data from MySQL database using ajax on button click and show to specific textarea please solve this .
Regards
Ahsan Javed

Comment: Jquery has a .val() method to set content in HTML for the referenced DOM element. Use: 
` $('#about_us').val(data.product_dec);`

Comment: i use but its not working you can test if you got solution please share with me Thanks

Comment: You need to check the API to which you are making call. in the `uri` field. Is it returnng data?

Comment: I Use it But Not Success Nothing Happen  i receive data but not showing in Rich Textarea

Comment: I have written an answer. Can you check if that works?

Comment: yes Please Check I update my code and question with image of Rich textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set the value `data.product_dec` in element with id `about_us`.
Since you are using Jquery I would suggest using `.val()` method of JQuery to achieve the desired outcome.

[Refer](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp):

Update:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('click', '.editbtn', function(){  
          var Pedit_id = $(this).attr("id");  
          $.ajax({  
               url:"/fetch/editproduct",  
               method:"POST",  
               data:{Pedit_id:Pedit_id},  
               dataType:"json",  
               success:function(data){ 
                    $('#about_us').val(data.product_dec);

               }  
          });  
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The url is probably the problem.If you are sending to a php document the add the extension:

```
url : "../fetch/editproduct.php",
```

And then the success function, the product_dec is not a method.I am not sure what you are trying to do there but make it:

```
$('#about_us').val(data+"product_dec");
```